# Cant push in ollama

Tags: ollama

Getting the following error in ollama:

> Error: stat
> /usr/share/ollama/.ollama/models/manifests/registry.ollama.ai/murtsu/marko/latest:
> no such file or directory

What to do? The marko model runs fine. I don't know what to do. I'm used to linux but shouldn't this work?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: On my Kubuntu build I have this location "usr/share/ollama/.ollama/models/manifests/registry.ollama.ai/library" do you have a 'library' folder with models in it? Can you cd into that folder? (murtsu/marko/latest) Maybe just missing library in your file location. Let us know if this helped.

Answer (score 0):

U can literally specify the OLLAMA_MODELS env variable when running ollama.
Let's clue in.

1. Make sure where u wanna put the models at or where does the ollama put the models at. For a Linux user, there are often two paths u might check out:

   (1)`~/.ollama/models`
   (2)`/usr/share/ollama/.ollama`

   Find where your models at, including the "marko".
2. Specify the model path and finish all the path-related errors, including the problem u facing and other alike problems (e.g. models disappear in list after restarting ollama).

   ```bash
   sudo systemctl edit ollama.service
   ```

   U open it, write the following text in the Nano window:

   > [Service]
   >
   > Environment="OLLAMA_MODELS=/usr/share/ollama/.ollama/models"

   or

   > [Service]
   >
   > Environment="OLLAMA_MODELS=/home/{your_user_name}/.ollama/models"

   Then save it by `CTRL+O` + `CTRL+X`.
3. Restart ollama by `sudo systemctl restart ollama.service` or `ollama serve`.

I hope it works for u since it worked for me.